# FireFox 40.0.2 & Selenium 2.45.0

Tags: firefox, selenium, cucumber

FireFox will get the error

"The page isn't redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies."

when I run cucumber test.

I can open firefox and can't get any error messages. And I have tried all clear cookie, cache , accept the third-party cookie and so on. But it didn't work.

Is there any other ways I can tried ?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading selenium to the latest version?

Comment: So many dependencies on selenium-webdriver, I can't change this. Maybe is there any other ways I can tried?

Comment: Sure, downgrade firefox to 36.0.5.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Is this firefox specific issue?

If not check the URL on other browsers

Faced this issue some time back and the reason being url redirection

Ex:

Assume there are two URLS :
URL A , URL B

Apparently there were two URL redirect entries in a table:

URL A was redirecting to URL B
URL B redirecting back to URL A

which caused the issue.

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: It doesn't matter on url.  I run every test which need to open firefox, it will get this error. And chrome can work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
Two tips:
   1.empty cache file
   2.empty download gems and bundle